# complex query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a small search engine in **php/mysql** and to use it in my future projects (websites or other web applications). I'm satisfied with fulltext search but still having some problems with grouping of results .

Example :

On websites like driverguide.com or kelkoo.co.uk (different type of websites) for each search has a detailed result . For driverguide.com after each search on the left are filters for Company , Device and Operating System with exact count for every category .

My question is : How can I organise and search on my multi tables to extract this result.
Can anyone describe a small example with 2-3 tables how to do that.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't a direct answer to your question but I would highly recommend using Solr.  It is a sophisticated open source search engine software.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

It also has DataImportHandlers where it will automatically update the indexes with your MySQL data.  We use Solr for all of our searching on our local business directory:

http://local.ksl.com/